# how to properly import jquery-ui in typescript file

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, typescript

i have included jquery like this

```
import $ = require('jquery');
```

and i am trying to make some div draggable like this.

```
constructor() {
    $("#mydiv-id").draggable();
}
```

but i get error that draggable is not a function. i do have jqueryui.d.ts but how to import it properly ?

require.config is like

```
var require = {
paths: {
    text: '../Scripts/libs/text',
    jquery: '../Scripts/libs/jquery-1.11.2',
    'jqueryui': '../Scripts/libs/jquery-ui',
    jscroll: '../Scripts/libs/jquery.jscroll', // and others
```

and i don't see any mention of jquerUI in    shim: section

Answer (score 0):

You need to have it referenced from your project. Recommend using tsconfig for this which can form you *compilation context* https://github.com/TypeStrong/atom-typescript/blob/master/docs/tsconfig.md

## Example

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "target": "es5",
        "module": "commonjs",
        "declaration": false,
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "noLib": false
    },
    "filesGlob": [
        "./**/*.ts",
        "!./node_modules/**/*.ts"
    ],
    "files": [
        "./globals.ts",
        "./linter.ts",
        "./main/atom/atomUtils.ts",
        "./main/atom/autoCompleteProvider.ts",
        "./worker/messages.ts",
        "./worker/parent.ts",
        "./typings/jquery/jquery.d.ts",
    ]
}
```

Comment: Any example of referencing anything like jquery in tsconfig ?

Comment: Added example  as requested

Comment: it looks like my project doesn't have tsconfig or anything that has configurations like this. do you recommended adding such a config file? because i believe it has something to do with require paths not setup correctly for jqueryUI because other stuff like knockout and toastr are setup and working fine.